# React multi carousel renders items wrongly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-multi-carousel

I started using Next js and I don't know whether it is problem regarding to it or React itself.

So the problem is that the "react-multi-carousel" does not work in my app. So, basically it works if I hardcode the values in there, but when I use my custom components, where the is map function, it does not render it properly. It takes 3  components as they are in one . You can verify it on the image I posted below. I tried to render `Compilations` component outside `SliderCarousel` component and it worked as it should, but when I pass `Compilations` as a child to `SliderCarousel`, it does not catch it and give it its own classes from `react-multi-carousel` library

Here is my code below and I ommited some imports and exports to focus attention on main parts

My `Compilation` component looks like this:

```
const compilation = ({ className, text, img }) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${className} ${classes.Compilation}`}>
            <img src={img} alt={text} />
            <div>
                <h3>{text}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

My `Compilations` component looks like this:

```
const compilations = ({ items, onClick }) => {
    const compilationsView = items.map(item => {
        return <Compilation key={item.id} onClick={() => onClick(item.id)} text={item.text} img={item.img} />;
    });
    return <React.Fragment>{compilationsView}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

`SliderCarousel` component looks like this

```
<Carousel
                swipeable={true}
                draggable={true}
                showDots={true}
                responsive={responsive}
                ssr={true} // means to render carousel on server-side.
                infinite={true}
                autoPlay={true}
                autoPlaySpeed={1000}
                keyBoardControl={true}
                customTransition="all .5"
                transitionDuration={500}
                containerClass="carousel-container"
                removeArrowOnDeviceType={[ "tablet", "mobile" ]}
                // deviceType={this.props.deviceType}
                dotListClass="custom-dot-list-style"
                itemClass="carousel-item-padding-40-px"
            >
                {items}
            </Carousel>{" "}
```

Here is my `pages/index.js` file

```
<SliderCarousel items={<Compilations items={getBookCarouselItems()} />} />
```

And the function is:

```
    {
        id: 0,
        img: "/static/images/main/books/slider-carousel/1.png",
        text: "ТОП-10 романов"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        img: "/static/images/main/books/slider-carousel/2.png",
        text: "На досуге"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        img: "/static/images/main/books/slider-carousel/3.png",
        text: "Бестселлеры"
    }
];
```

[image]

I hope that you can help me resolve this problem, cause I have no idea how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

actually this carousel makes a `<li>` for each element to manoeuvre the carousel effects as you can see in the inspect screenshot

in your code

```
const compilations = ({ items, onClick }) => {
    const compilationsView = items.map(item => {
        return <Compilation key={item.id} onClick={() => onClick(item.id)} text={item.text} img={item.img} />;
    });
    return <React.Fragment>{compilationsView}</React.Fragment>;
};
```

you are wrapping your map list in fragment and hence carousel got only one item as a component and hence one `<li/>`

so in order to work you'll have to pass the map list (i.e. array) of `<Compilation />`

```
const allCompilations = (items) => items.map(item => {
        return <Compilation key={item.id} onClick={() => onClick(item.id)} text={item.text} img={item.img} />;
    });
```

to you carousel as children

```
<SliderCarousel items={allCompilations(getBookCarouselItems())} />
```